# how is it possible to have multiple articles from sub-site shown on main wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I have 8-9 subsites on the main site. I would like to have at least 2-3 latest articles/posts from each of the subsite blogs on the main site home page. is there any plugin/widget that can do or is there any code that we can put in the main site theme to publish multiple posts from every single subsite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @redfox however i used plugin network extended. that made it easier by using the shortcode and it helped to increase posts from every sub site to display on main site.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [switch_to_blog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) function in order to query posts from any site on the network. Then, you might want to do something like:

```
// Switch to a particular site on the network
switch_to_blog( $site_id );

// Retreive the latest 3 posts
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
     'order'           => 'DESC'
);
$latest_articles = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $latest_articles->have_posts() ) {
    $latest_articles->the_post();
    // do some stuff such as the_title(), the_content(), etc.
}

// Restore the original query
wp_reset_query();

// Get back to the original site
restore_current_blog();
```

Hope that helps!